# Discard mouse events on NSWindow based on click position

Tags: cocoa, calayer, nswindow, nsevent

Let's say I have a floating, borderless, circular `NSWindow`.

It is circular because the content view simply draws a red circle.

That content view needs to be layer-backed (`[contentView setWantsLayer:YES]`), because I'm applying *CoreAnimations* on it, e.g., animated scaling.

**Usually**, the clickable area of a NSWindow is defined by the transparency of the pixels of the content view. However, once the content view of a NSWindow becomes layer-backed, transparent areas will also receive clicks, unfortunately.

In my case, this is a serious problem, because I only want to receive clicks within the radius. But now, a click within the rect of the window, but beyond the circle radius, will activate the window (and thus, the entire app), which it shouldn't. Also the window is draggable via the corner of its content view.

[image: click location]

My initial thought was to implement `[NSWindow sendEvent:]` in a subclass and check whether the click was performed within the radius, using `[theEvent locationInWindow]`. I thought I could simply discard the event, if it's beyond the radius, by not calling `[super sendEvent:theEvent]` then. This however did not work: I noticed, that the mouseDown:; window method is called even before the sendEvent:; method.

I've search a lot but the only idea I found, was to have a proxy like non-layer backed NSWindow on top of the window, which delegates clicks conditionally, but this led to unpredictable UI behavior.

Do you guys have any idea, how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried intercepting events at the application level by subclassing `NSApplication` and implementing the `-sendEvent:` override?

Comment: I've just tested it, with no success. Even when I try to discard **any** event by never calling ```[super sendEvent:]```in the NSApplication subclass, the window keeps being movable via mouse dragging. Also, overwriting ```[NSApplication postEvent:]``` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a few weeks, I came to the following results:

A) **Proxy window**:
Make use of a non layer-backed proxy window, which is placed on top of the target window as a child window. The proxy window has the same shape, as the target window, and since it is not layer-backed, it will properly receive and ignore events. The proxy window delegates all events to the target window by overwriting `sendEvent:`. The target window is set to ignore all mouse events.

B) **Global Mouse Pointer observation**:
Install both a global and local event monitor for `NSMouseMovedMask|NSLeftMouseDraggedMask` events using `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask` and `addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask`.   The event monitors disable and enable ignoring mouse events on all registered target windows based on the current global mouse position. In the case of circular windows, the distance between the mouse pointer and every target window must be calculated.

Both approaches work well in generally, but I've been experiencing some unpredictable misbehaviors of the child window approach (where the child window is 'out-of-sync' of its parent's position).

**UPDATE:** Both approaches have some significant disadvantages:
In A), the proxy window sometimes may be out of sync and may be placed slightly off the actual window.

In B), the event monitor has a big impact on battery life while moving the mouse, even if the app is not the front-most application.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441015/click-through-custom-nswindow

Answer (score 2):

If you want to Discard mouseDown event based on position you can use the:

```
CGPathContainsPoint(path,transform,point,eoFill):Bool
```

Setup your path to match your graphics. Circles, ellipses, rectangles, triangles or paths and even compositional paths (paths with holes in them).

Comment: And then what? hitTest() can be overridden to return nil in that case but that doesn't seem to send the click on to the next window..

Comment: override the hitTest method and handle your code inside the hitTest method. Then forward the hitTest event with super if the mouseDown point is outside the path.

Comment: Basically: return nil, stops the event flow. forwarding the event with super keeps propagating the event.

Comment: Returning nil alone doesn't seem to do the trick to give focus to the window behind our window, see mini-example: https://github.com/aphofstede/TransparentWindowClickthroughTest/blob/master/TransparentWindowClickthroughTest/MaskedView.swift

Comment: My previous comment has two parts. The first part stops the event flow. The second part keeps the event flow propagating. Try to do the second if you wan't GUI elements behind to register the event. This works for NSViews and should work for NSWindow as well.

Comment: Here is another approach for adding custom bezier masks to NSWindows: http://stylekit.org/blog/2016/01/23/Chromeless-window/  (see the part about "custom bezier shape") It might not be exactly what you are looking for but it may give you another idea.

Comment: Here is an article i've written about hitTesting that might shed some light on the concept: http://stylekit.org/blog/2016/01/28/Hit-testing-sub-views/

Comment: Ah, was that you, I read through that and was contemplating leaving a comment, guess I already did :) I managed to get it working using a masked layer, but my real app has a more complex layer set-up and I can't copy it over directly, I'll try to replicate it in the demo project, see if that clarifies things

Comment: Here's a version that works well, using a mask layer: https://github.com/aphofstede/TransparentWindowClickthroughTest/tree/7fbc6248f47da0760c38d49d6c4ad5ce59627e3d

Comment: Note that using .resizable in the window's styleMask will break transparent click-throughs. Seems like a bug to me, I opened a bug report @ Apple and implemented my own resizing for now.

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the resize handles that appear at the edges of a Window. The solution for resizing that apples provides is meant for rectangular windows. So they probably decided to break transparent click throughs in cases where a window isn't rectangular. Pioneering work you are attempting non the less.

Comment: You're probably right. I don't see why it wasn't possible to pull it apart though and let developer's define their resizing cursor tracking areas separately if need-be and let the transparency handling do its thing..

Comment: I implemented custom window resizing once by using a combination of NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask and NSEvent.removeMonitor. It should do the trick. Some Elbow grease may apply ;)