# Click through custom NSWindow

Tags: swift, macos, nswindow

I have custom NSWindow with custom NSView set as its contentView.

The window gets initialized with:

```
[window setOpaque:NO];
[window setBackgroundColor: [NSColor clearColor]];
[window setHasShadow: NO];

[window setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents: YES];
[window setLevel: NSFloatingWindowLevel];
```

Content view, in its `drawRect` draws simple circle filled by solid color.

All this works OK - the window appears on desktop and I see that circle.

The only thing that does not work: the whole window rectangle is not transparent for mouse clicks. If I will click outside the circle (but inside invisible window box) my view receives mouseDown events but I expect underlying windows (or desktop) to be activated instead.

It appears that I need something like hitTest method to be overridden on my NSWindow class but unfortunately there is no such menthod.

So is the question: is it possible to have NSWindow with custom click through areas in OS X. If "yes" then how?

UPDATE:

Looking on [RoundTransparentWindow](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/Introduction/Intro.html) sample that works as expected - the window is click through in transparent areas. Seems like this piece:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
   ...
   // Reset the window shape and shadow.
    if (shouldDisplayWindow) {
        [[self window] display];
        [[self window] setHasShadow:NO];
        [[self window] setHasShadow:YES];
    }
}
```

in CustomView.m is related to the problem but even with it (in my case) I cannot achieve transparency for mouse clicks :(

Comment: Have you set the `ignoresMouseEvents` property of the window at any point? (You shouldn't.) Rather than that code from RoundTransparentWindow, try just calling `-invalidateShadow` from the content view's `-drawRect:`. You say the `-drawRect:` just draws the circle. Does it attempt to fill its bounds before doing so? Finally, try it without turning on the window's `acceptsMouseMovedEvents`.

Comment: I am not touching `ignoresMouseEvents`.  `invalidateShadow` does not help. As of drawing - nothing really fancy `CGContextAddEllipseInRect/CGContextFillPath`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question:

On OS X, in order to have windows with custom shapes with click through on transparent areas following conditions must be met:

1. The window **must be** created with only `NSBorderlessWindowMask` set by `[window setStyleMask: NSBorderlessWindowMask]` for example.
2. You **MUST NOT** call `[window setIgnoresMouseEvent: NO]` on it. As that method  clearly contains a bug on Apple's side.
3. contentView of the window **MUST NOT** use layers. So something like this `[[window contentView] setWantsLayer: YES]` effectively disables click through too.

Just in case: all this was about layered windows handling in [Sciter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/859098/Sciter-multiplatform-embeddable-HTML-CSS-scripting) on OS X

[image: "Sciter clock" sample on Windows, OS X and Linux]

Comment: I would not say that setting `ignoresMouseEvents` is buggy. It's just that there are three states (ignores all events, does not ignore any events, and ignores events on transparent areas). The window starts in the third state and you can set the property to switch to and between the first two, but once you do you can never get back to the original state. It's an unfortunate design.

Comment: "unfortunate design" is kind of oxymoron, isn't it?

Comment: @KenThomases comment about the 3-stateness of `ignoresMouseEvents` is worth its weight in gold. Thank you.

Comment: It seems to work for me even when the `wantsLayer = true`

Comment: I think this answer is outdated? At least regarding the 3rd point. I made a borderless transparent window with a layer backed content view. The click is pass through on transparent area. If I add any opaque layer on top of the content view, these opaque layers are clickable.

Comment: On MacOS 14 Sonoma, this problem appear again as the invisible window is blocking click, wonder if anyone have fix for it?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the absolutely incredible answer of c-smile and the absolutely incredible comment of KenThomases,

Here's the basic and simple way to do a "full screen floating app thing" where clicks go through, and conversely you can click on "your" stuff.

You'll need this (for reasons I don't fully understand, the window won't expand fully without it),

[image]

and then ...

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    guard let w = view.window else {
        print("what the?")
        return
    }
    w.styleMask = .borderless
    // note that you DO NOT do this: w.ignoresMouseEvents = true
    // see comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29451199/294884

    w.collectionBehavior = [.fullScreenPrimary]
    w.level = .floating
    w.isMovable = false
    w.titleVisibility = .hidden
    w.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
    w.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.isHidden = true
    w.standardWindowButton(.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true
    w.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
    w.hasShadow = false
    w.isOpaque = false
    w.backgroundColor = NSColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)
    w.zoom(self)

    guard let screen = w.screen ?? NSScreen.main else {
        print("what the???")
        return
    }
    w.setFrame(screen.visibleFrame, display: true)
}
```